# How can I insert CSS, META, etc. tags into the head tag using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, content-management-system, head

I use a hosted CMS that has a bug that won't allow me to insert content into the `<head>`.

I thought about using Javascript to insert the code needed into the head but will that even work? If a page is read `<head>` then `<body>` will it even matter to put the code into the head using javascript if the head has already been read or do I mis-read how the browsers work?

If you can put content into the head of a page and it will work with all major browsers what is the javascript to do that? (I am a novice when it comes to javascript.)

Note: I use a *hosted* CMS and do not have access to any server side scripting.

***EDIT:***

I need to add `CSS` and `META` tags.

The CSS would be something like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
 .slideshow img { display: none }
 .slideshow img.first { display: block }
</style>
```

The META could look like this:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Title Text" />
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:url" content="URL Path" />
<meta property="og:image" content="IMG Path" />
<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpeg" />
<meta property="og:image:width" content="620" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="541" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="My Site" />
```

Those are examples but similar to what I will be adding.

Comment: What elements do you need to add to the head? CSS? JavaScript? Title tag? Meta tags?

Comment: @JCOC611 who would use JS to add JS?

Comment: @ColeJohnson - Many people. Most of the JavaScript API will do that.

Comment: @Derek damn you, beated me by 2 seconds. +1

Comment: @JCOC611 - I updated question to reflect what I would be adding, mainly META and CSS elements.

Comment: @Lynda For CSS it shouldn't make much of a difference, seeing as all major browsers recognize stylesheets inside the `body` - I thought this wasn't standard, but even Chromium's GCF examples use stylesheets inside the `body` which run in IE. Now for the meta tags, I'm not sure what's their purpose, but I guess crawlers may not recognize those dynamically added tags.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté - The Meta tags are used for [Open Graph Tags](http://ogp.me/). I use them with Facebook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a CSS script:

```
var ele = document.createElement("style");
ele.type = "text/css";
ele.innerHTML = "CSS CODE"; // Replace with CSS code.
document.head.appendChild(ele);
```

For the Meta Tag (although I doubt it would work, since the software that looks at Meta Tags usually doesn't execute JavaScript code):

```
var ele = document.createElement("meta");
ele.property = "propertyName"; //Replace with property name.
ele.content = "CSS CODE"; // Replace with content.
document.head.appendChild(ele);
```

Comment: I believe you may be right about the `meta` tags. I tried the method for CSS and it worked in FF and IE9 but breaks in IE 8. Thoughts?

Comment: Try it with `document.body.appendChild(ele);` (body instead of head), and see if it works.

Comment: Yeah, but it probably works too! Anyway, another thing you might want to try is changing your DOCTYPE to trigger IE8 in Compatibility mode.

Comment: I added IE Conditional Comments for IE8 and below (inside the body tag.) For all other browsers I am using the JS above. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
var ele = document.createElement("script");  //Tag name
ele.src = "your_link.js";                    //URL
document.head.appendChild(ele);              //Insert into <head>
                                             //Done.
```

Comment: Thanks, I will give this a try and see what happens. One more question if I want to use CSS like my question (I updated it since your answer => ) How would I add that?

Comment: @Lynda - Take a look at JCOC611's answer, it answers all your questions. ;) By the way, you should use jQuery, it is super-convenience in adding elements and manipulating the DOM.

Comment: I do use jQuery on my site and am fully open to jQuery solutions. =>